# Rails Active Record translation: Auto capitalize/downcase?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, internationalization

Taking the default wording it self, in some case, user model will be displayed as 'user' (lowercase) as in "3 errors prohibited this user from being saved" and in some case as 'User' (capitalized) (as in nested-model form: User name can't be blank). That should be applied to other Latin-based language, right? How can I specify a model name translation so that Rails (Active Record?) display it in lowercase or in capitalized depends on the context (as pointed above)?

Answer (score 0):

See https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/locale/en.yml. There are answers for both your doubts.

Comment: So the answer is: It's currently not supported?